# Help calculating the second homology group of $\mathbb{R}P^2 \times S^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology

I need help calculating the second homology group of $\mathbb{R}P^2 \times S^1$.  I found all the other homology groups using the Mayer-Vietoris sequence.  Any suggestions?  I can't use Kunneth.

Comment: WHy can't you use Künneth?

Comment: Because the qual problem says don't use Kunneth.

Comment: Why did you not get all the homology groups by Mayer-Vietoris?